# How make a fade slideshow loop?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to change my css class background image every few seconds. It is working great the problem is it just stops after it shows the last image.  Can anyone show me what to add to this code so that it will continuously loop itself?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(fadeDivs, 5000); //call it every 2 seconds
    function fadeDivs() {
      var visibleDiv = $('.bckgnd:visible:first'); //find first visible div
      visibleDiv.fadeOut(400, function() { //fade out first visible div
        var allDivs = visibleDiv.parent().children(); //all divs to fade out / in
        var nextDivIndex = (allDivs.index(visibleDiv) + 1) % allDivs.length; //index of next div that comes after visible div
        var nextdiv = allDivs.eq(nextDivIndex); //find the next visible div

        var lastDiv = $('.backgnd3');
        var firstDiv = $('.backgnd1');
        if (currentDiv != lastDiv) {
          var nextdiv = allDivs.eq(nextDivIndex); //find the next visible div
        } else {
          var nextdiv = firstDiv; //the next div will be the first div, resulting in a loop
        }
        nextdiv.fadeIn(400); //fade it in
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.backgnd1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 452px;
  background: url ('http://quaaoutlodge.com/sites/all/themes/marinelli/img/backgrounds/backgnd1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
}

.backgnd2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 452px;
  background-image: url ('http://quaaoutlodge.com/sites/all/themes/marinelli/img/backgrounds/the_lodge.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
}

.backgnd3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 452px;
  background-image: url('http://quaaoutlodge.com/sites/all/themes/marinelli/img/backgrounds/getting_here.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
}

.index_roof_background {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 452px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="index_roof_background">
  <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 2;display:block; background-color:#000;" class="bckgnd backgnd1"></div>
  <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 2;display:none; background-color:#000;" class="bckgnd backgnd2"></div>
  <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 2;display:none; background-color:#000;" class="bckgnd backgnd3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding a better User Experience you would also allow the user to pause the gallery on mouseenter. That way the user can enjoy some image details. (It's the way all better galleries work today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>A better approach:</sup>

- You don't need all those `backgnd2` classes since you have only those DIVs inside a common parent.
- Don't use inline styles! Use your `stylesheet`.
- Don't use fixed width (px). Use %  for responsive design.
- 2000*1331px images are
  not suited for the web. Specially not for mobile devices. Care about
  your user's bandwidth. When setting a background-image to `cover` you
  don't need to worry about it being `repeat`ed.
- Make your JS more flexible to element's indexes, count your elements using `length`.
  Create a "current index counter", iterate over it increment it and
  resetting using `%` (reminder).
- For a better UX, allow the user to **pause on hover**.

Here's an eample:

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready. $ alias in scope.

  $('.gallery').each(function() {

    var $gal = $(this),
      $sli = $gal.find(">*"),
      tot = $sli.length,
      c = 0,
      itv = null;

    $sli.hide().eq(c).show(); // Hide all but first slide

    function anim() {
      c = ++c % tot; // increment/reset counter
      $sli.fadeOut().eq(c).stop().fadeIn();
    }

    function play() {
      itv = setInterval(anim, 3000);
    }

    function pause() {
      clearInterval(itv);
    }

    $gal.hover(pause, play); // Pause on hover
    play();                  // Start loop

  });

});
```

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.gallery>* {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/0bf?text=1)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/f0b?text=2)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/0fb?text=3)"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the good pointers @RokoCBuljan.  I love the functionality of this.  Only problem I am having with it is I have another div with a form inside of the div I am rotating the background.  How do I keep it from getting pushed down and keep it inside of the parent div?  I tried changing the .bgFader > div z-index to 2 and my inside div z-index to 10 but that isn't working.

Comment: @RokoCBuljan  Update:  I changed the inside div to position: relative and had to set top postion to top: -400.  It is working perfect now.  If you can think of a better way to do this or give me any reasons of why I shouldn't do it the way I did it please let me know.  Otherwise thanks for the help!

Comment: @bg2982 I don't know what CSS you used so I cannot give you a better suggestion since I cannot see your code. Forcing something to position -400px seems like you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First put the firstDiv, lastDiv in their own variables.

Then you will need something like this

```
if (currentDiv != lastDiv) {
    var nextdiv = allDivs.eq(nextDivIndex); //find the next visible div
} else {
    var nextdiv = firstDiv; //the next div will be the first div, resulting in a loop
}
nextdiv.fadeIn(400); //fade it in
```

Tell me if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Sachin.  I updated my code above to try and do what you said.  I am brand new at javascript so wasn't really sure as how to put the first and last div in their own variable.  Was I anywhere close to what I was supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 timeouts to make it loop. A timeout only fires once. The FadeOutDivs function counts down, each time setting a timeout to call itself. Then at zero it fades sets a timeout the call fadeInDivs which start the whole cycle over.

I've got this running on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPermE).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var interval = 2000;
    var fadeDuration = 400;
    var allImages = $('.bckgnd');
    var count = allImages.length - 1;
    var imageCount = allImages.length;

    setTimeout(fadeOutDivs, interval);

    function fadeOutDivs() {

        allImages.eq(count).fadeOut(fadeDuration);

        console.log(count);

        if (count > 1) {

            count--;

            setTimeout(fadeOutDivs, interval);

        } else {

            count = allImages.length - 1;

            setTimeout(fadeInDivs, interval)
        }

    }

    function fadeInDivs() {

        allImages.fadeIn(fadeDuration);

        setTimeout(fadeOutDivs, interval);

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brian.  I tried to use this and it still changes backgrounds but still stops after the 3rd/final image is shown.

Comment: Can you post the relative part of your html and the css for the bckgnd. I can probably give you a simpler solution.

Comment: posted html and css.  Thanks for your help